# Rails routing error 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am new to rails and  trying to NOT use `resources :todos` and build my routes one by one. 
However, I get following error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TodosController#show
>       Couldn't find Todo with 'id'=id

**My routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/todos' => 'todos#index'
  get '/todos/:id' => 'todos#show'
end
```

**My controller:**

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

  def index 
    @todos = Todo.all
  end 

  def show
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```

**My view:**

```
<h1>Todo show page</h1>
<p>Title: <%= @todo['title'] %></p>
<p>Description: <%= @todo['description'] %></p>
<%= link_to 'Back to todo list', todo_path %>
```

**My rake routes results:**

```
todos GET  /todos(.:format)     todos#index
```

It is not showing my route for show that i set it.
I appreciate it if you could help out. Thank you.

Comment: What URL are you trying to access? And is that the entire output of your routes file?

Comment: When i try to get to following url  http://localhost:3000/todo/show it keeps saying ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TodosController#show
Couldn't find Todo with 'id'=id

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine and it should perfectly work. I only think that you don't pass a correct `Todo` id that does exist in the database.

So when you are trying your code by visiting: `http://localhost:3000/todos/1` make sure that `1` or whatever id is a real id for a record in your database.

Otherwise you will always get that error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

From your `rails console` you can try something like: `Todo.first.id` to get the first todo's id. Then use this ID to open the `todos/:id` route.

Comment: I also tried this, it works perfectly. also my `rake routes` show both index and show. Maybe OP forgot to mention something important....

Comment: @reiallenramos, I am trying to not use reserouces :todos for my application but set up each routes one by one. Can anyone pls direct me to info(i couldn't find) to study how to set up routes without using resources tool?